# Docker - Permission denied while trying to access folder created in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, permission-denied

I have problem with my Dockerfile (code below)

```
 FROM node:4.2.6
 MAINTAINER kamil
 RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash node
 RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
 WORKDIR /home/node/app
 COPY /myFolder .
 USER node
 COPY --chown=node:node . .
 RUN ["chmod", "777", "/home/node/app"]
 ENTRYPOINT /home/node/app
 CMD ["node myApp.js"]
```

I'm building docker image with 
`"docker build -t my_docker_image ."`
 and it finished with no errors.

Next I am running it with command `"docker run --name my_run_docker_image -d my_docker_image"` and its also finished without errors, but when I want to check status of my new container with `"docker ps -l"` command i'm getting info that status of my container is "EXITED".

Hence i'm trying to run it once again with command `"docker start -a my_run_docker_image"` but I'm receiving error:

> "node MyApp.js: 1: node myApp.js: /home/node/app: Permission denied"

I was trying to run it with root user, without specified user but every time I have the same issue.

Comment: Given the previous errors in your Dockerfile that would prevent the image from building, how do you know you are running the image defined by the Dockerfile above? Please show the output from the build and then the following run command with your permission error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a problem with your user add command.

Change

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash/node
```

to

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash node
```

And also

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && -R node:node /home/node/app
```

Needs to change to

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for try, but unfortunately its still the same error. Cannot run my docker image. ;/

Answer (score 0):

The ENTRYPOINT and CMD tell Docker what command to run when you start the container.  Since ENTRYPOINT is a bare string, it’s wrapped in a shell, and CMD is ignored.  So when you start your container, the main container process is

```
/bin/sh -c '/home/node/app'
```

Which fails, because that is a directory.

In this Dockerfile, broadly, I’d suggest two things.  The first is to install your application as root but then run it as non-root, as protection against accidentally overwriting the application code.  The second is to prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT in most cases, unless you’re clear on how they interact.  You might come up with something more like:

```sh
FROM node:4.2.6
MAINTAINER kamil
WORKDIR /app # Docker will create on first use
COPY myFolder .
RUN useradd node # its shell should never matter
USER node
CMD ["node", "myApp.js"]
```